# How to delete documents with no subdocuments in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have a couchbase document with id `x`

x has  no subdocument , As all were deleted in some subdoc operation , it is something like this `{}`

I want to delete all such empty docs with no subdocs. Is it possible in couchbase ,using an N1QL query or otherwise? I tried googling for solutions, but I found no relevant solutions.

Thanks for taking the time to read the question till the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query requires primary index.

```
DELETE FROM default AS d
WHERE d = {};
```

The following query uses ix10 as covered index. Index contain only empty objects.

```
CREATE INDEX ix10 ON default(OBJECT_LENGTH(self))
WHERE OBJECT_LENGTH(self) = 0;

DELETE FROM default AS d
WHERE OBJECT_LENGTH(d) = 0;
```

You can verify with the following data. The select should only give "k003"

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES ("k001",1), VALUES ("k002",{"a":1}),  VALUES ("k003",{});

SELECT META(d).id
FROM default AS d
WHERE OBJECT_LENGTH(d) = 0;
```